# How does SoundCloud aggregate the playcount

Tags: soundcloud

My team and I are looking to use the embedded SoundCloud widget for a site we're building. We'd like to use the API to track the total number of plays by tracking the `playback_count` property for each track, however I've not been able to find specific information on how/when this is incremented. I'm looking to answer:

1. Does is only track completed plays? Or started plays?
2. Does it track multiple plays by the same user/client?
3. Does it track plays made by the streaming URL (in a custom player) or only the embedded player/SoundCloud website?
4. It appears that the `playback_count` is not updated immediately, is the `playback_count` updated (nightly/hourly etc.)?
5. Is there a list of supported browsers/devices for the
   embed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. SoundCloud increments the count as soon as the play button is clicked ([reference](http://statsandengagement.help.soundcloud.com/customer/portal/articles/2155889-stats-basics)).
2. Plays are tracked by any user which is not the track owner (see above reference).
3. Tracks are only counted by the web player, mobile app, mobile website, and official embeds. Requests to any of the `/streams` endpoint values (ex: `http_mp3_128_url`), do not count towards the play count.
4. `playback_count` values may be invalid due to caching ([reference](http://statsandengagement.help.soundcloud.com/customer/portal/articles/2167060-stats-aren-t-updating)).
5. The embed widget is supported by most browsers which support HTML5 media playback. See [these blogs posts](https://blog.soundcloud.com/tag/widget/) as well as SoundCloud's own HTML5 audio benchmark project [here](https://github.com/soundcloud/areweplayingyet).

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect